# biblatex + biber + babel: configuration for polish language and style of bibliography (missing polish.sty)

Tags: biblatex, babel, biber

This problem is probably trivial, but it's very important to me. After hours spent on searching the solution I couldn't find it.

My LaTeX document works very well with `biblatex`, `biber` and `babel`, but I couldn't achieved the look of bibliography like in Polish books/articles/thesis. Generally it's look like in English (default), but not sure.

**Some additional errors:**

```
Package csquotes Warning: Load 'inputenc' before 'csquotes' on input line XXX.
Package csquotes Info: Checking for multilingual support...
Package csquotes Info: ... found 'babel' package.
Package csquotes Info: Adjusting default style.
Package csquotes Warning: No style for language 'polish'.
```

#### My minimal example

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
...
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
  style=numeric, % numeric, alphabetic, authoryear, ect.
  sorting=nty,
  isbn=false,
  backend=biber,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
...
\begin{document}

% include some chapters
\include{chap_prolog}
...

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**bibliography.bib**

```
@Book{KrysWlod99,
  author = {Włodzimierz Krysicki and Lech Włodarski},
  title = {Analiza matematyczna w zadaniach},
  publisher = {Wydawnictwo Naukowe PWN},
  year = {1999},
  part={1},
  address = {Warszawa},
  isbn = {83-01-01460-1}
}

@Article{Popper84,
  author = {Popper K. R.},
  title = {Literatura na świecie},
  journaltitle = {Epistemologia bez podmiotu poznającego},
  year = {1984},
  number = {12}
}
```

#### The output

[image: Bibliograpthy printout]

...but it should look something like this:

[ 1 ] Włodzimierz Krysicki i Lech Włodarski, *Analiza matematyczna w zadaniach*, Wydawnictwo Naukowe PWN, Warszawa 1999, tom 1.

[ 2 ] Popper K.R., *Epistemologia bez podmiotu poznającego*, ,,Literatura na świecie'' 1984 nr 12.

How to **switch on** or declare `biber` and `biblatex` for polish style of bibliography?

Or how to write own Polish bibliography style for biblatex and biber?

Did I done something in wrong in the example?

PS. I know I could use `thebibliography`, but this is not the solution for automatic bibliography.

Comment: It is not biblatex but csquotes that is complaining. So look at the documentation of csquotes how to create a quoting style for polish or how to use one of the existing quoting style instead.

Comment: `\DeclareQuoteAlias{german}{polish}` will let `csquotes` use `german` when `polish` is specified, which gives the quote style you ask for.  For changes to the `biblatex` layout see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/15925

Comment: Thank you @AndrewSwann for fast reply. The solution for quotations is almost quite good, but the last of quote's mark is wrong according to this example [Quotations for Polish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_variation_in_quotation_marks#Polish)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, at least for first levels quotes , the polish style is the same as `croatian`, which is defined in `csquotes`. For the remaining questions, a few patches to biblatex solve them (you need to load the `xpatch` package):

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,polish]{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}

    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \DeclareQuoteAlias{croatian}{polish}
    \usepackage[%
    style=numeric, % numeric, alphabetic, authoryear, ect.
    sorting=nty,
    isbn=false,
    abbreviate = false,
    backend=biber,]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{polbiblio.bib}

    \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
    \renewbibmacro*{in:}{}

    \usepackage{xpatch}

    \xpatchbibdriver{book}{%
    \newunit
    \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
    \printfield{part}}
    {}%
    }
    {%
    }{}{}

    \xpatchbibdriver{book}{%
    \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
    }
    {%
    \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
    \newunit
    \printfield{volume}%
    \printfield{part}
    \usebibmacro{finentry}
    }{}{}

    \DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{nr.  #1}% number of a journal

    \DeclareFieldFormat
    [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
    {title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
    %
    \renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
    \printfield{series}%
    \setunit{\addspace}}%
    \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{issue}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
    \newunit}

    \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \iffieldundef{issue}
    {\usebibmacro{date}}
    {\printfield{issue}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{date}}%
    \newunit}

    \renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit}

    \begin{document}

    \nocite{*}

    \printbibliography

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Bernard, this is great answer and good point to start own customization. You save my day and probably the day many of my fellows.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way to define a Polish quote style for `csquotes`.  I have based it on the code in 
`csquotes.def` for `german`, but with appropriate changes of quote symbols.  As mentioned in  my comment above [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/15925) should help you to get started configuring the `biblatex` style and I won't address that here.

[image: Sample text]

[image: Sample bib]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{polski}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle[quotes]{polish}
  {\quotedblbase}
  {\textquotedblright}
  [0.05em]
  {\quotesinglbase}
  {\fixligatures\textquoteright}
\DeclareQuoteAlias[quotes]{polish}{polish}
\DeclareQuoteOption{polish}

\usepackage[
  style=numeric, % numeric, alphabetic, authoryear, ect.
  sorting=nty,
  isbn=false,
  backend=biber,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}

\enquote{Najstarsze zdanie w języku polskim \enquote{Day, ut ia pobrusa, a ti poziwai} zapisano w 1270 roku\dots}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```